# Regular expression in Powershell to remove unwanted string

Tags: regex, powershell

Hi how to write a regular expression in powershell to remove any string that started with | D|Ref.Doc. ?

```
| D|Ref.Doc.  |Row|DocumentNo|CoCd|Pstng Date|Period
| W|100003574 |  3|65697957  |CACS|01/15/2016|     1
| W|100003574 |  3|65697957  |CACS|01/15/2016|     2
| W|100003574 |  3|65697957  |CACS|01/15/2016|     3
| D|Ref.Doc.  |Row|DocumentNo|CoCd|Pstng Date|Period
| W|100003575 |  3|65697957  |CACS|01/15/2016|     1
| W|100003575 |  3|65697957  |CACS|01/15/2016|     2
| W|100003575 |  3|65697957  |CACS|01/15/2016|     3
```

Expected output

```
| W|100003574 |  3|65697957  |CACS|01/15/2016|     1
| W|100003574 |  3|65697957  |CACS|01/15/2016|     2
| W|100003574 |  3|65697957  |CACS|01/15/2016|     3
| W|100003575 |  3|65697957  |CACS|01/15/2016|     1
| W|100003575 |  3|65697957  |CACS|01/15/2016|     2
| W|100003575 |  3|65697957  |CACS|01/15/2016|     3
```

Comment: `-notlike'| D|Ref.Doc.*'`

Comment: How to use -notlike in this command ? $d = Get-Content -path $path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-Content $path | ? { $_ -notmatch '^\| D\|Ref\.Doc\.' }
```

Note how `|` and `.` need to be `\`-escaped in order to be interpreted as *literals*.
`^` anchors the regular expression at the *start* of each input line.

However, as @PetSerAl suggests in a comment, instead of using a *regular expression*, you can get away with a simpler *wildcard* pattern in this case:

```
Get-Content $path | ? { $_ -notlike '| D|Ref.Doc.*' }
```

Note that `?` is an alias for the filtering `Where-Object` cmdlet.

Comment: Thanks for the command. 1 more question how to add or condition into command Get-Content $path | ? { $_ -notmatch '^\| D\|Ref\.Doc\.' } ? for example I want to exclude any line starting at | D\|Ref\.Doc\. or | |